# ASP.net - strongly typed dataset usage

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, ado.net, dataset

I have a very simple SQL table of products, that I want to edit with a asp.net GridView.

1) I created a DataSet/Adapter with Insert/Select/Update commands for the `products` table.
2) In Default.aspx, I have the following Grid:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Produkt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductManufacturer" HeaderText="Hersteller" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" HeaderText="Preis" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView> <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Produkt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductManufacturer" HeaderText="Hersteller" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" HeaderText="Preis" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

3) The code behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static dsProducts ds = new dsProducts();

    protected void GridBind()
    {
        ProductTableAdapter tableAdapter = new ProductTableAdapter();
        tableAdapter.Fill(ds.Product);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Product;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        this.GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridBind();

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ds.HasChanges()==true)
        {
            ProductTableAdapter adapter = new ProductTableAdapter();
            adapter.Update(ds.Product.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
        }

        // Exit edit mode
        this.GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        // Update the grid
        GridBind();

    }

}
```

The problem is, `ds.hasChanges` is always false. So after editing and clicking "update", it simply loads the original data.

What is the Problem?

Comment: Do not use a static DataSet in ASP.NET! All   requests share this object which will cause locks and other threading issues including data incosistency. Apart from that, all objects are disposed at the end of the page's life-cycle (which was probably the reason for making it static). But you don't even need the original datasource for the update. Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating(v=vs.110).aspx) or other tutorials for more informations.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you, but I did just add the static because I thought it might have to do something with my problem, it was private before. I mean, I could use the Adapter directly to update, but why can't I use the typed dataset for that?

Comment: Accessors and the static-modifier are orthogonal concepts, so there is no relation between `private` and `static`. Why do you want to use the `DataSet`? It will be destroyed on each and every postback because HTTP is a stateless protocol. So you are creating a blank new `DataSet` everytime. Also, the dataset's `HasChanges` is always false because it is never changed. That's simply not how `GridView`-updating works, the `DataSource` is `null` anyway on a postback.

Comment: Thanks, you are right of course, I don't know what I thought there. however, in the MSDN example, they just update the table in a session, not the database. I simply can't find a good example. And And it's hard to believe that there is no better (strongly typed) way to handle `GridViews RowUpdating` than with statements like `dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Description"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;`

Comment: It's not best-practise to store the `DataTable`/`DataSet` in `Session` even if it works (as opposed to `static`) and might be the best option in an intranet application with few users. However, don't do it so in general. You should search a good tutorial about `GridView`s, [`RowUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating(v=vs.110).aspx) for example has also `Keys`, `OldValues` and `NewValues` collections as argument. If you use `TemplateField`s you could also find the controls via `ID` and create readable code.